# Angular 2 AOT - referencing not-yet-created AppModuleNgFactory

Tags: angular, webpack, angular2-aot

I have a set of components in a module with an example application under a different module in the same project. I have an existing JIT build that works fine, and I'm trying to transition to an AOT build where I'm hitting issues. Specifically, `/src/index.aot.ts (2,34): Cannot find module './aot/app/examples/app.module.ngfactory'`.

How do I setup webpack with `AotPlugin` to properly build an AOT version of my application to a local `dist` directory?

`/src/index.aot.ts`

In this file, AppModuleNgFactory cannot resolve because it doesn't exist. Nothing is generated to any aot directory currently, and I'm not sure why.

```
import 'core-js/client/shim';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';

import '@angular/common';
import 'rxjs';

import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';
import {AppModuleNgFactory} from '../aot/app/examples/app.module.ngfactory';
import {platformBrowser} from '@angular/platform-browser';

enableProdMode();
platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory);
```

`/tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types/"
    ],
    "target": "ES5",
    "types": [
      "node",
      "jasmine",
      "es6-shim"
    ]
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "filesGlob": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "!node_modules/**"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist/",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "aot/",
    "skipMetadataEmit": true
  }
}
```

`webpack-dist.conf`

```
...imports     
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/index.aot.ts'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loaders: [
          'json-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|otf|eot|svg|png|jpg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
        loader: 'file-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'tslint-loader',
        enforce: 'pre'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loaders: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: 'css-loader?minimize!sass-loader!postcss-loader'
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: [
          '@ngtools/webpack'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loaders: [
          'html-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    FailPlugin,
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: conf.path.src('index.html')
    }),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
      conf.paths.src
    ),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"production"'
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('index-[contenthash].css'),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({name: 'vendor'}),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      options: {
        postcss: () => [autoprefixer],
        resolve: {},
        ts: {
          configFileName: 'tsconfig.json'
        },
        tslint: {
          configuration: require('../tslint.json')
        }
      }
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {from: 'index.html'}
    ]),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
      Tether: 'tether'
    }),
    new AotPlugin({
      tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.json',
      entryModule: './src/app/examples/index.ts#AppModule'
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      output: {comments: false},
      compress: {unused: true, dead_code: true, warnings: false} // eslint-disable-line camelcase
    })
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(process.cwd(), conf.paths.dist, 'aot'),
    filename: '[name]-[hash].js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [
      '.webpack.js',
      '.web.js',
      '.js',
      '.ts'
    ]
  }
};
```

What am I missing? Why do I need to reference a file that doesn't exist in a bootstrap file like `index.aot.ts`?

Full error output:

```
ERROR in ~/work/project/src/index.aot.ts (2,34): Cannot find module './aot/app/examples/app.module.ngfactory'.

ERROR in Could not resolve "./src/app/examples/app.module" from "./src/app/examples/app.module".

ERROR in ./src/index.aot.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './aot/app/examples/app.module.ngfactory' in '~/work/project/src'
 @ ./src/index.aot.ts 4:29-79
```

Edit: After removing platformBrowser() and the generated import, I'm down to this inexplicable error:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './../$$_gendir/src/app/examples/app.module.ts.ngfactory'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **don't** need to do put the following in the `main.ts`:

```
platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory);
```

You have to leave the same bootstrap code in `main.ts` as you have for non-AOT build:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
```

Angular AOT loader will refactor the code to `bootstrapModuleFactory` when generating AOT build. See [here in the sources](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/24d31cd5229c338b3236daffe49f9cdb36af9354/packages/%40ngtools/webpack/src/loader.ts#L267). The important thing is that `skipCodeGeneration` option should be `false` - which is default.

Comment: That removes 1 level of error, and the referenced source seems to indicate this is correct, but I'm still one step away, and one of the original errors still persists.


ERROR in Could not resolve "./src/app/examples/index.ts" from "./src/app/examples/index.ts".

ERROR in ./src/index.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './../aot/src/app/examples/index.ts.ngfactory' in '/Users/a554173/work/angular2-student-loans-components/src'
 @ ./src/index.ts 8:27-82

Comment: It seems like I definitely need an entryModule definition, although I'm not sure what exactly is wrong with what I have.

Comment: @StefanKendall, this error seems to be out of scope for this particular question. Can you maybe create another question where you show the project structure of your application? Usually you don't have to do anything special to get a build AOT with AOTPlugin. I tested it by creating new angular-cli project then running `ng eject` then modifying new AOTPlugins options (remove skipCodeGeneration) and then running `npm build` successfully builds the project

Comment: I did not. But I'm currently stripping the project down to try and create a minimal error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46279458/angular-2-aot-cant-resolve-gendir-ngfactory